# High CPU utilization from kblockd

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I have been experiencing a problem where I can no longer SSH into my raspberry Pi 2 after it is idle for over a week or so. At first I thought it was frozen, but when I hooked it up to a display it shows the following:

```
  1  [||||                                                   5.8%]     Tasks: 101, 109 thr; 3 running
  2  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]     Load average: 2.20 2.08 2.06
  3  [|||||||||||                                           17.5%]     Uptime: 10 days, 17:48:22
  4  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||99.4%]
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||258/735MB]
  Swp[                                                     0/99MB]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 3813 pi         20   0  4976  3212   956 R 98.0  0.4 10h27:46 kblockd
18503 pi         20   0  4976  3216   960 R 97.0  0.4  2h45:52 kblockd
 2400 root       20   0 30976 19104  8404 S  6.0  2.5  6:42.62 /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
 6807 pi         20   0  5180  2992  2296 R  5.0  0.4  0:01.97 htop
 2592 pi         20   0 98104 22624 19772 S  3.0  3.0 27:11.02 lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
 6793 pi         20   0 91920 17020 14788 S  3.0  2.3  0:01.31 lxterminal
 2590 pi         20   0 15176 10332  8032 S  1.0  1.4  0:01.49 openbox --config-file /home/pi/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml
 6812 pi         20   0 84740 16976 15008 S  0.0  2.3  0:00.52 leafpad
 2003 nobody     20   0  2032  1460  1344 S  0.0  0.2  0:12.53 /usr/sbin/thd --daemon --triggers /etc/triggerhappy/triggers.d/ --socket /va
```

My questions are:

**1.)** What is `kblockd` and why is it using so processing power?

**2.)** Has anybody had this issue?

**3.)** Is this typical behavior when an SD card is about to fail?

This is about the only resource I found on this: [kblockd](http://www.lazysystemadmin.com/2012/04/kblockd-process-high-utilization-in.html)

Other Notes:

- Raspian is up to date
- Installed: wit.ai Python library, Adafruit Python libraries, BrickPi_Python, rplay, omxplayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A high kblockd CPU usage could be due to various reasons:

1. Large IO queue - Server not managing disk writes quick enough
2. Low memory situations where memory can't be allocated to processes. Sometimes this is caused by memory leaks.
3. SD card driver failure, causing EXT3 journals to be aborted

To diagnose it further, you can use iostat to find what process is waiting for disk I/O.

[This post](http://projects.nuschkys.net/2012/05/15/testing-a-new-sd-card-under-linux/) may be helpful in checking your SD card.

Comment: I will try iostat next time this happens. Thank you!